# Can I treat a file as a list in python?

Tags: python, list, file

This is kind of a question, but it's also kind of me just hoping I don't have to write a bunch of code to get behavior I want. (Plus if it already exists, it probably runs faster than what I would write anyway.) I have a number of large lists of numbers that cannot fit into memory -- at least not all at the same time. Which is fine because I only need a small portion of each list at a time, and I know how to save the lists into files and read out the part of the list I need. The problem is that my method of doing this is somewhat inefficient as it involves iterating through the file for the part I want. So, I was wondering if there happened to be some library or something out there that I'm not finding that allows me to index a file as though it were a list using the `[]` notation I'm familiar with. Since I'm writing the files myself, I can make the formatting of them whatever I need to, but currently my files contain nothing but the elements of the list with `\n` as a deliminator between values.

Just to recap what I'm looking for/make it more specific.

1. I want to use the list indexing notation (including slicing into sub-list and negative indexing) to access the contents of a list written in a file
2. A accessed sub-list (e.g. `f[1:3]`) should return as a python list object in memory
3. I would like to be able to assign to indices of the file (e.g. `f[i] = x` should write the value `x` to the file `f` in the location corresponding to index `i`)

To be honest, I don't expect this to exist, but you never know when you miss something in your research. So, I figured I'd ask. On a side note if this doesn't exist, is possible to overload the `[]` operator in python?

Comment: You can overload the `[]` operator by defining `__getitem__`. Also, when you say "index", you mean "position in file" (as opposed to line number), right?

Comment: As a bare minimum to make this *efficient*, you'll want to write records with fixed frame lengths to allow leveraging `seek` to locate the items you want without needing to account for variable line lengths

Comment: @gmds By index, I mean the position in the list being stored in the file. Currently means line number for me since that's what separates elements of the list but I'm currently thinking I want to do what donkopotamus is suggesting with fixed frame lengths (which means I should switch to a binary file?), but my understanding of "position in file" is the precise char/byte I'm located at which is not what I want since each frame spans a multiple bytes. I think what I want to do is use `seek` and `struct` to read/write to the file using c-type formatting, but I need to do more research to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is purely numeric you could consider using `numpy` arrays, and storing the data in `npy` format.  Once stored in this format, you could load the memory-mapped file as:

```
>>> X = np.load("some-file.npy", mmap_mode="r")
>>> X[1000:1003]
memmap([4, 5, 6])
```

This access will load directly from disk without requiring the loading of leading data.

Comment: If the OP can't fit all their data into memory, is there a way to write this file in the first place?

Comment: Sure ... using [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) for example.

Comment: I think that might be helpful to include in your solution, was my point.

Comment: This looks like it might be what I need, but looking at memmap's documentation alerted me of the python `mmap` module. Right now I'm not really sure which one I need because they appear to do largely the same thing memmap is just specific to `numpy`. Is there a reason why you specifically suggested memmap over mmap?

Comment: Only because, for quick access, you need a framed protocol that will use fixed length records to store elements (meaning the implementation can quickly seek to the right place) ... if you just `mmap` your text file you will **not** have fixed length records and cannot optimise seeking to the correct index ... there are plenty of **other** alternatives to, such as [`hdf5`](https://www.h5py.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this by writing a simple class, I think:

```
class FileWrapper:

    def __init__(self, path, **kwargs):
        self._file = open(path, 'r+', **kwargs)

    def _do_single(self, where, s=None):
        if where >= 0:
            self._seek(where)

        else:
            self._seek(where, 2)

        if s is None:
            return self._read(1)

        else:
            return self._write(s)

    def _do_slice_contiguous(self, start, end, s=None):
        if start is None:
            start = 0

        if end is None:
            end = -1

        self._seek(start)
        if s is None:
            return self._read(end - start)

        else:
            return self._write(s)

    def _do_slice(self, where, s=None):
        if s is None:
            result = []
            for index in where:
                file._seek(index)
                result.append(file.read(1))

            return result

        else:
            for index, char in zip(where, s):
                file._seek(index)
                file._write(char)

            return len(s)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return self._do_single(key)

        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            if self._is_contiguous(key):
                return self._do_slice_contiguous(key.start, key.stop)

            else:
                return self._do_slice(self._process_slice(key))

        else:
            raise ValueError('File indices must be ints or slices.')

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return self._do_single(key, value)

        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            if self._is_contiguous(key):
                return self._do_slice_contiguous(key.start, key.stop, value)

            else:
                where = self._process_slice(key)
                if len(where) == len(value):
                    return self._do_slice(where, value)

                else:
                    raise ValueError('Length of slice not equal to length of string to be written.')


    def __del__(self):
        self._file.close()

    def _is_contiguous(self, key):
        return key.step is None or key.step == 1

    def _process_slice(self, key):
        return range(key.start, key.stop, key.step)

    def _read(self, size):
        return self._file.read(size)

    def _seek(self, offset, whence=0):
        return self._file.seek(offset, whence)

    def _write(self, s):
        return self._file.write(s)
```

I'm sure many optimisations could be made, since I rushed through this, but it was fun to write.

This does not answer the question in full, because it supports random access of *characters*, as supposed to lines, which are at a higher level of abstraction and more complicated to handle (since they can be variable length)